# Resistors connected to op-amps

Tags: operational-amplifier, resistors, homework

[image]

I'm trying to solve this assignment and I'm not sure what to do with all those resistors. Should I calculate an equivalent resistance for each group? And how do the resistors connected between the terminals of the op-amps influence the circuit?

Comment: I'd suggest finding a good intro to designing with op-amps. Understanding the principle behind the high-gain differential feedback circuit makes working with these remarkably straightforward.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @keshlam! Does it happen to know any good intros?

Comment: Haven't gone looking online. An excellent book, if still available, is Jung's IC Op Amp Cookbook; after a chapter or two of explanation of the essential concept he provides an extensive pile of useful circuits with brief discussion of the design decisions he made for each one.

Comment: Hint: an ideal op-amp means that V(+) - V(-) (i.e. the error signal) is equal to 0. That alone will allow you to get rid of some resistors. 
Second, an ideal op-amp can also sink or source an infinite amount of current; therefore, R4 and R10 can be 0.1ohm or 1Tohm, it wouldn't matter to the op-amp since it can always provide the current needed to produce the set gain.

Comment: The first part of the schematic is a "log" function called "transdiode" schematic. Google it.

Comment: Yes, each "group" (opamp) can be calculated independently.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log_amplifier https://www.ijareeie.com/upload/2013/august/16_A%20REVIEW.pdf https://www.ti.com/lit/an/snoa575b/snoa575b.pdf